# Are there examples of functions in $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ whose Fourier series divergent ("weakly")?

Tags: fourier-analysis, limits-and-convergence

It is wellknown that there is a convergence in norm for Fourier series in $L_p$, if $1<p<\infty$, but are there some examples for pointwise divergence if $p=1,\infty$ in books, or somewhere? I have only found Kolmogorov example, but it is too complicated, and i don't need divergence almost everywhere

Comment: There are continuous functions with Fourier series divergent at a point, so your $L^p$ assumptions seems somewhat beside the point here. (Also, since you talk about Fourier series, presumably you're on the circle, so $L^{\infty}\subset L^p$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any function that is in $L^1$ but not in $L^\infty$ will have some point in whose neighbourhood it is unbounded, and the Fourier series is likely to diverge at such a point.  A simple example is
$$ f(x) = \ln(1-\cos(x)) = -\ln(2) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2 \cos(nx)}{n} $$
where the series diverges at multiples of $2\pi$.

EDIT: For Fejér's example of a continuous function whose series diverges at a point, see e.g. Edwards, "[Fourier series](https://books.google.ca/books?id=LsDkBwAAQBAJ)", sec. 10.3.1.

Comment: But why $ln(1-cos(x))$ is in $L_1$, why is it integrable?

Comment: As $x \to 0$, $\ln(1-\cos(x)) \sim 2\ln|x|$, which is an integrable singularity.

Comment: Thanks! But I also can't understand why does Uniform Boundedness Principle implies divergence of Fourier series in $L_\infty$, I have read it somewhere, but it seems not to be so obvious for me

Comment: @user228494: Uniform boundedness principle.  An interesting method to show existence.  But your question asks for "some examples" and UBP is not the way to produce explicit examples.

Answer (score 0):

See Katznelson's Harmonic analysis (page 61) for a very simple example of a continuous function whose fourier series diverges at a dense set of points. I believe du Bois Reymond is the person responsible for the first such example.